# How do spiritual fathers of Catholic Church explain a sudden urge to pray?

Tags: catholicism, spirituality, spiritual-theology

I'd like to know how Catholic spiritual masters explain the urge to pray. Is it considered inspired by the Holy Spirit? Should we surrender to that urge?
I was doing some research on that topic, but I didn’t find any reference from a Catholic perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Holy Ghost gives grace to help us begin to pray.

"*Should we surrender to that urge?*" We should "pray without ceasing" ([1 Thes. 5:17](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=59&ch=5&l=17-#x)).

Since we cannot do anything without Christ ([Jn. 15:5](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=15&l=5-#x): "without me you can do nothing"), the Holy Ghost needs to give us initial, [prevenient](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35764)* grace before we can even begin a good action of prayer.
<sub>*"Prevenient" literally means "coming before"; prevenient grace is the initial unmerited grace that comes before other graces.</sub>

We grow in charity by making more intense acts of charity, which are begun under the Holy Spirit's initiative. Prayer is a means toward the end of growth in charity (perfection).

From Fr. [Antonio Royo Marín, O.P.](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22=Royo%20Mar%C3%ADn,%20Antonio,%20O.P.%22)'s excellent [***Theology of Christian Perfection***](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6163) [p. 408](https://archive.org/details/TheologyOfChristianPerfection/page/n207):

> Without the [actual](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31646) [prevenient](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35764) grace, man can do absolutely nothing in the supernatural order, and without the more intense grace, the more intense act [of charity] is impossible. That [actual grace](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31646) which is more intense cannot be [merited](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34851), for this would be a contradiction*; but it can be infallibly impetrated [asked of God], although under a gratuitous title, through prayer which fulfills the necessary conditions.

<sup>*Because then the effect (more intense charity) would be greater that the cause (less intense charity); cf. [axiom 6.4](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/catholicteaching/philosophy/axiomata.htm): "The cause is greater than the effect."</sup>

Every change (e.g., from a state of non-prayer to a state of praying) is due to God, the [Unmoved Mover / Unchanging Changer](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6742).

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting approach

Comment: @brigittethecat It only scratches the surface. Your questions are quite deep.

Comment: @brigittethecat Besides [Fr. Antonio Royo Marín, O.P.](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22=Royo%20Mar%C3%ADn,%20Antonio,%20O.P.%22), [Fr. Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.](http://www.christendom-awake.org/pages/thomas-crean/saint-in-heaven.htm) is another great 20th century master of spiritual theology, [whose works](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22=Garrigou-Lagrange,%20R%C3%A9ginald,%20O.P.%22) are well-worth reading; he occupied St. Thomas Aquinas's university's Angelicum's first chair of "ascetical and mystical theology."

Comment: @brigittethecat Check out also Fr. Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.'s [_Three Ages of the Interior Life_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6076).